# Using axios to access the kraken API

Tags: node.js, axios, kraken.com

I have been trying to create a personal client for the Kraken API. I am a self thought programmer and it's very possible there's a silly bug somewhere that I cannot find. I keep getting the message invalid api key. The API key I am using is however freshly generated and I can't seem to find out what's wrong. Can I please get a second pair of eyes to look over this repository for me and try to identify the error. I am able to make public calls but whenever I try private calls, I get the invalid API key error. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. Thanks. The code causing the error is in the kraken.js file.

https://github.com/awjwhyte/kraken-client

Comment: Comparing yours with official, https://github.com/nothingisdead/npm-kraken-api/blob/master/kraken.js the way you sign the data is different. This bit `${this.nonce}nonce=${this.nonce}&${serialize(postData)}`, comparably they doing just `${this.nonce}${serialize(postData)}`

Comment: that was what I was initially doing but it didn't work. I decided to change to the current method of signing based on the instructions on https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001491786-API-Error-Codes. I'm not sure what is wrong as both methods of signing are not working.